# Inline Javascript to Unobtrusive JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I channge this inline javascript to Unobtrusive JavaScript?

```
<input type="button" value="Text1" onclick="this.value=this.value=='Text1'?'Text2':'Text1';">
```

Thank you!

---

Thank you for your answears, but it doesn't work. My codes are:

php

```
<input id=\"button1\" type=\"button\" value=\"Text1\">
```

js file

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function(){
    this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
}
```

or

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.value = (this.value === 'Text1') ? 'Text2': 'Text1';
}, false);
```

I tried everything you told me, but it didn't work! Neither with jquery.

Have I forgotten something?

Comment: that's not even valid inline JS?

Comment: "this.value=this.value=='Text1'?'Text2':'Text1';" there was a missing " ' "

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zw2Fp/. Where are you placing the code?

Comment: Yup, this was the error. I fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to the input and do this:

```
document.getElementById('somebutton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.value = (this.value === 'Text1') ? 'Text2': 'Text1';
}, false);
```

or with jQuery

```
$('#somebutton').on('click', function () {
    this.value = (this.value === 'Text1') ? 'Text2': 'Text1';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Text1" />
<script>
  (function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    return inputs[inputs.length - 1];
  })() // returns the input element
  .onclick = function(){
    this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
  }
</script>
```

This script has to be placed immediately after the element (or at least somewhere before the next `input` element on the page).

### Demo

If you are okay with adding an `id` to your element that script becomes a bit simpler and you can put it anywhere after the `input` exists (such as right before your closing `</body>` tag:

```
<input id="somename" type="button" value="Text1" />
```

Script:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('somename').onclick = function(){
    this.value = this.value === 'Text1' ? 'Text2' : 'Text1';
  }
</script>
```

### Demo

Comment: i want to know the purpose of (function(){ in your reply cause i never use that. can't it be (inputs[inputs.length -1]).onclick ... ?

Comment: Yeah,  that would work jist as well. As long as it's all inside the function so that the vraiable `inputs` doesn't become global

Comment: i see. by that way we can prevent the variable scope very local. ok.